# How to return JsonResult

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm having trouble writing this AJAX method.

I want to return a `JsonResult`. (Seems like the logical thing to do.) All the examples I could find use `Json()` to convert the result to a `JsonResult`.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetScoreResults(string userId, int chapterId)
{
    return new Json(ChapterScoreResultsModel.Create(DbContext, userId, chapterId));
}
```

But when I try this:

> The type or namespace name 'Json' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

However, I can't find this symbol anywhere and all the articles I found that used it didn't seem to do anything special. I did find the symbol in the namespace `System.Web.Helpers` but when I add a `using` for that, I get the error:

> Cannot create an instance of the static class 'Json'

What is the *current* way to return a `JsonResult` from an AJAX method?

Comment: Remove `new` - just `return Json(...)`

Comment: new keyword is not required 
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/2ed7ae/jsonresult-type-in-mvc/

Comment: @StephenMuecke: OMG! I can't believe I did not see that. (I had added the new because originally I was not using `Json`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Controller class has a [Json method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.json(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Controller.Json(System.Object)). Invoking it returns a `JsonResult`. Note that it's method, not a constructor. You do not put the `new` keyword in front of the method call.

```
return Json(ChapterScoreResultsModel.Create(DbContext, userId, chapterId));
```